# Excel Formula prob

Tags: excel

Can you help me to my formula?

Here's my formula

```
=IF(A1<=1000,0,IF(TA1<=2000,((A1-1000)*0.2)))
```

The problem is when I'm putting another "IF", Excel says

> Too many arguments for this function

```
=IF(A1<=1000,0,IF(A1<=2000,((A1-1000)*0.2)),IF(A1<=3000,(((A1-2000)*0.25)+500)),IF(A1<=4000,(((A1-3000)*0.3)+1000)),IF(A1<=5000,(((A1-4000)*0.35)+1500)))
```

And that is the formula I want to input. Please help me fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of excel you are using?

Comment: 2016 @harun24hr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in bracket. Try below formula

```
=IF(A1<=1000,0,IF(A1<=2000,(A1-1000)*0.2,IF(A1<=3000,((A1-2000)*0.25)+500,IF(A1<=4000,((A1-3000)*0.3)+1000,IF(A1<=5000,((A1-4000)*0.35)+1500)))))
```

Comment: If you found it working then you should accept (Tick as green) it as other visitor can know it is useful answer and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your usage of brackets. Excel is seeing the formula as 'complete' after your first usage of two closing brackets, after the *0.2. Remove all these second brackets and add them to the end:

```
=IF(A1<=1000,0,IF(A1<=2000,((A1-1000)*0.2),IF(A1<=3000,(((A1-2000)*0.25)+500),IF(A1<=4000,(((A1-3000)*0.3)+1000),IF(A1<=5000,(((A1-4000)*0.35)+1500))))))
```

If you edit the cell and move the cursor to just after this second closing bracket, notice how the 'hint' no longer highlights any part in bold. Delete this second bracket and the hint and formula colouring will return. Then just do for the rest.

Comment: Thankyou, it works now and I learned new things on excel. Thankyou again for help!